# How to call input file which is qlready in the package

Tags: url, input, hadoop

In my Hadoop Map Reduce application I have one input file.I want that when I execute the jar of my application, then the input file will automatically be called.To do this I code one class to specify the input,output and file itself but from where I am calling the file, there I want to specify the file path. To do that I have used this code:

```
 QueriesTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/src/main/resources/test") 
 but it is not working     (cannot read the input file from the generated jar)
```

so I have used this one

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/src/main/resources/test") here I am getting the problem of URL. So please help me out. I am using Hadoop 0.21.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to tell us with your resource loading, but the usual way to add an input file is this:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
Job job = new Job(conf);

Path in = new Path("YOUR_PATH_IN_HDFS");
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, in);

job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class); // could be a sequencefile also
// set the other stuff
job.waitForCompletion(true);
```

Make sure your file resides in HDFS then.

Comment: Thank for your help :-).Could you tell me how we can add input file in our package and call it to execute automatically just to test the application.So just we will execute the jar nothing else where the input file is in the package itself.

Comment: You can use the FileSystem within your jar and upload it using your ResourceAsStream method. Do you need code for that?